# How to send Serilog data to logservice?

Tags: c#, logging, rabbitmq, serilog

I need to send Serilog logdata from Server A to Server B through a RabbitMQ channel. To do this I'm creating a serilog custom sink on Server A that sends the data. The problem is how It should send this data so Server B can easily re-log it with Serilog to an external log service and keep the structure logging intact.

The log code on Server A might look something like this :

```
var position = new { Latitude = 25, Longitude = 134 };
var elapsedMs = 34;

log.Information("Processed {@Position} in {Elapsed:000} ms.", position, elapsedMs);
```

This will then be packed in to a LogEvent object by Serilog and then sent to the sinks :

I simple sink might look like this :

```
    public class MySink : ILogEventSink
{
    private readonly IFormatProvider _formatProvider;

    public MySink(IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        _formatProvider = formatProvider;
    }

    public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        //Sending logEvent over MQ
    }
}
```

How can I send this LogEvent to Server b where I just can re-log it right in to Serilog and still preserve the structure logging without any lost data?

Comment: ILogger.Write(LogEvent) didn't work for you?

Comment: @Fildor, where do you mean? I suspect that the custom sink have to in some way serialize the LogEvent, send it over MQ to Server B which will deserialize the LogEvent and then post it to Serilog. Is it really that easy?

Comment: That's where I meant - on B in the MQ receiver. It _may_ be that easy, but I am not _sure_. I was just wondering why it _shouldn't_ work, if we have that overload for LogEvent ?

Comment: You don't have to ask us if it's that easy. Go try it! If it doesn't work and you can't figure it out, then provide a [mcve] and clearly explain what's not working about your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the [Serilog.Formatting.Compact NuGet](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact) that will translate the Serilog LogEvent to a compact JSON string. This JSON string can then be read back into a Serilog LogEvent with [Serilog-formatting-compact-reader NuGET](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact-reader). After some testing I can conclude that this works great.

There might be types that the JSON sterilizer can´t handle but I haven’t found any yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at this project, that does exactly what you are looking for: [log server](https://github.com/K-Society/KSociety.Log)

Here you will also find the RabbitMQ Sinks.

In my project you will find the following things:

1. Server as a simple consumer of messages from RabbitMQ

[This is the LogEventHandler](https://github.com/K-Society/KSociety.Log/blob/master/Src/01/04/KSociety.Log.Biz/IntegrationEvent/EventHandling/LogEventHandler.cs) that is triggered with each new message from RabbitMQ queue.

2. Serilog.Sinks.RabbitMQ as publisher of messages

[This is the core](https://github.com/K-Society/KSociety.Log/blob/master/Src/01/Sink/KSociety.Log.Serilog.Sinks.RabbitMq/Sinks/RabbitMq/RabbitMqBatchedSink.cs) of the publication of the messages in the RabbitMQ sinks.

In my case i don't use json formatting but i use protobuf binary serialization which is more compact.

[This is README](https://github.com/K-Society/KSociety.Log/blob/master/README.MD) where you can find more details on how to use this logging system.

Comment: Please explain your code also to understand

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).